# How to customize react-native-gifted-chat in React Native 0.61

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

Just wanted to share.

I was finding it difficult to customize the default UI for this package. The official documentation wasn't that helpful.

Luckily, I was able to solve it.

See answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make your imports

```
import {GiftedChat, InputToolbar,...} from 'react-native-gifted-chat'
```

### **Customizing the InputToolbar**

***Note:*** `InputToolbar` must be imported since we want to customize it

Create a function called `customInputToolbar` that will return the custom UI

```
const customtInputToolbar = props => {
  return (
    <InputToolbar
      {...props}
      containerStyle={{
        backgroundColor: "white",
        borderTopColor: "#E8E8E8",
        borderTopWidth: 1,
        padding: 8
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

***Note:*** `props` must be an argument.

***Tip:*** Since all props for the `InputToolbar` were not listed in the official github page (https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat), you can `Cmd + Left Click` on the `InputToolbar` tag while in your editor. This will navigate you to the source file within which all props are listed. **Be careful not to edit anything !!**

Include the `renderInputToolbar` as a prop in the `GiftedChat` component

```
<GiftedChat
    messages={chatMessages.messages}
    onSend={messages => sendMessage(messages)}
    renderInputToolbar={props => customtInputToolbar(props)}
    ...
 />
```

***Note:*** Remember to pass `props` as an argument to the function. Without this, the UI will not display

*You're done !!*

### **Customizing the SystemMessage component or using an absolutely custom UI**

Include `SystemMessage` in your import

Create a function called `customSystemMessage`

```
  const customSystemMessage = props => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.ChatMessageSytemMessageContainer}>
        <Icon name="lock" color="#9d9d9d" size={16} />
        <Text style={styles.ChatMessageSystemMessageText}>
          Your chat is secured. Remember to be cautious about what you share
          with others.
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Include `renderSystemMessage` as a prop in your `GiftedChat` component

*You're done*

*Hope this helps!*